# Add the existing key for list of values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I want to assign the existing key to list of values in dictionary. I tried many ways. but only getting the updated one. please anyone help me the below scenario.

**Input data:**

```
var1 = {'key':[{'a':1,'b':2},{'af':11,'bf':12}]}
```

**required output Be :**

```
{
'key': {'a':1,'b':2},
'key': {'af':11,'bf':12}
}
```

Comment: Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys...

Comment: Dictionary keys must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible only with keys like `key1`, `key2` and so on... because duplicate keys aren't allowed in python.

So try this:

```
print({f'key{i}': v for i, v in enumerate(var1['key'], 1)})
```

Output:

```
{'key1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'key2': {'af': 11, 'bf': 12}}
```